# connect c++ & Mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, database, boost, fedora

anyone can tell me what's wrong in my prg ? 
It say's me :
With this prg i would view a table from MySQL.

This is my code :

```
int main(void)
{
    //QString mydb = "mydb";
    QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("mydb");

      //Setup the database
    database.setDatabaseName( "mydb" );
    database.setUserName( "root" );
    database.setPassword( "testpw" );

    if ( !database.open() )
      qDebug("Couldn't open DB");

}

 but i have the errors :
```

and i dont know why, its my first c++ / mysql prg and i think i have forget anything to download or to include .

> /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:33: undefined
>   reference to `QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:33: undefined
>   reference to`QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString const&, QString
>   const&)' /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:36:
>   undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(QString const&)'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:37: undefined
>   reference to`QSqlDatabase::setUserName(QString const&)'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:38: undefined
>   reference to `QSqlDatabase::setPassword(QString const&)'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:40: undefined
>   reference to`QSqlDatabase::open()'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:41: undefined
>   reference to `qDebug(char const*, ...)'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:41: undefined
>   reference to`QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:43: undefined
>   reference to `QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:43: undefined
>   reference to`QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()'
>   /home/boldt/src/workspace/tester/Debug/../src/tester.cpp:41: undefined
>   reference to `QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()' ./src/tester.o: In
>   function`QString::QString(char const*)':
>   /usr/include/QtCore/qstring.h:419: undefined reference to
>   `QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int)' ./src/tester.o: In
>   function`QString::QString(QLatin1String const&)':
>   /usr/include/QtCore/qstring.h:694: undefined reference to
>   `QString::fromLatin1_helper(char const*, int)' ./src/tester.o: In
>   function`QString::~QString()': /usr/include/QtCore/qstring.h:880:
>   undefined reference to `QString::free(QString::Data*)'

Comment: And for those who don't understand German, what is the error? And where in the code is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I use for QT -> MySql.  I personally try to stay completely clear of boost, QT is a much cleaner and complete solution.

Firstly, you'll want these includes:

```
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlError>
```

Inside your project file, please add sql to your Qt variable:

```
QT += core sql
```

I believe this logic needs to run inside a Qt event loop.  I recommend using a single shot timer.  Qt offers many example programs that will get you started.

Open up the database.  You don't need to store the database instance variable unless you need to connect to more than 1 database at a time.  QT will keep an internal pointer for you.

```
QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QMYSQL" );

  //Setup the database
database.setDatabaseName( db );
database.setUserName( usr );
database.setPassword( pass );

if ( !database.open() )
  qDebug("Couldn't open DB");
```

Here is some code for reading data out of the DB.  In this code I only take the first row returned.  This could be changed by calling query->next() multiple times:

```
QString sql = QString("SELECT id, type, name FROM table WHERE id = %1").arg( id );

//Go through looking for my mac address
QSqlQuery query( sql);
if ( query.next() )
{
  int id       = query.value( 0 ).toInt();
  int type     = query.value( 1 ).toInt();
  QString str  = query.value( 2 ).toString();

  return true;
}
```

Here is a function to insert bulk data.  Note in many implementations there is a limit to the number of rows you can insert by a single execBatch() call.  I don't know what the limit is, or how to find it.  However <= 128 should be safe:

```
bool Database::storeTable( QString table, QStringList &field_list,
                           QHash<QString, QVariantList> &fields )
{
  QString sql;
  QStringList q_marks;
  QSqlQuery query;
  int i;

    //Create my question marks
  for ( i = 0; i < field_list.size(); i++ )
    q_marks.append( "?" );

    //Create my query
  sql = QString::fromUtf8("INSERT INTO %1 ( %2 ) VALUES ( %3 )")
          .arg( table)
          .arg( field_list.join(','))
          .arg( q_marks.join(','));

    //Setup my query
  if ( !query.prepare( sql ) )
  {
    qDebug("Couldn't prepare SQL store statement\r");
    return false;
  }

    //Attach my values and finish
  for ( i = 0; i < field_list.size(); i++ )
    query.addBindValue( fields[ field_list[i]] );

    //Setup my query lookup
  bool result = query.execBatch();
  if ( !result )
    qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. but i have a question.
QString sql = QString("SELECT id, type, name FROM table WHERE id = %1").arg( id ); what a id , type , name  ? where i can get the id from my database / table ?

Comment: In my example, I use a where clause to match to a specific primary key (id).  You could remove the where clause, and the entire table's contents will be accessible.  The best thing to do is take this example, research it with Qt Assistant and write some test programs.

Comment: can you help me again ? look at my new question here, i have edit its. thank you very much.

Comment: thelittlePanda, I quickly looked at your update.  Note you need to add sql to your QT variable inside the project file. I believe you need to add this logic into a valid Qt event loop.  If you don't know what that is, please look at an example Qt program, and load this code into a single shot timer.

Comment: Please note, QT assistant is a GREAT tool.  It has extensive examples that will get you up and running quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the include additional directories for boost library.

```
"Additional Include Directories"
C:\Users\user\Desktop\boost_1_53_0\boost_1_53_0
```

Here's a detailed explanation with examples 
    http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-from-the-visual-studio-ide

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but i use Fedora ( Linux ) i i dont find boost_1_53_0.
Only libboost_system.so.1.54.0 , libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 , libboost_date_time.so.1.54.0 :(

Comment: Add the include directories where the cpp and headers are and the linker folder should be: L/usr/local/lib/  and then you call g++ with -lboost_filesystem .Hope it helps.